# How do I create space between text and floating embedded Iframe YouTube video?

Tags: iframe, youtube, embed

I have embedded a YouTube video in my Wordpress blog with the following code:

```
    <div style="float: right;"><iframe width="425" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/WUHkW2Iqt8g?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

My problem is that the video is too close to my text in the article. I have searched on Stack Overflow but - as I have no html experience - couldn't figure it out on my own. I Googled and thought I could add an "Hspace" code but it didn't work. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `margin-left` style on the div. The div's style attribute might look like `style="float:right;margin-left:10px"`, where you can choose whatever size you think looks good.